# invert d3 color scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I'm wondering, given a color, is there a way to get the value that color represents inside of a `d3.js` color scale?

I have preprojected topology rendered in canvas, and would like to show the value of the topology on hover. I can get the pixel value of the area the user is hovering over quite easily, but converting that back to the original value seems difficult.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add a sample input and expected output for much clarity of your question.. and the code what you have tried so far

Comment: Depends what type of scale you're using. You can't invert the value for ordinal scales (including the built-in colour scales).

Comment: thanks @LarsKotthoff, thought so, but figured it was worth a shot asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your color array:

```
var myColor = {
    dom: [ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ],
    rag: [ "#ffffff", "#fff5f0", "#fee0d2", "#fcbba1", "#fc9272", "#fb6a4a", "#ef3b2c", "#cb181d", "#a50f15", "#67000d" ]
};
```

then assign it to your scale on d3:

```
var color = d3.scale.threshold()
              .domain(myColor.dom)
              .range(myColor.rag);
```

on "hover", in case using jQuery search inside array for a value

```
if ($.inArray( "#"+yourVariableHereWithTheColorSelected, myColor.rag )) {
   // do something because is true
}
```